# open image after clicking on single.php with different stylesheet in wordpress

Tags: attachments

i have single.php like

```
if(have_posts())
{while(have_posts()){
the_post(); 
//content displayed
}}
```

in the content i have some images. As i click on the image it opens in very simple manner without any background or header included in it. So how can i apply style on that page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It sounds like your images are linking to the image file. When you upload images, try linking them to the attachment page instead, or look for a plugin that opens image links in a lightbox. Try both solutions and see which you prefer.

Comment: I'd upvote this if you'd explain _how_ to do what you suggest.